# How to create XML File in Xcode

Tags: xml, xcode

How can I create a new XML File in Xcode? There is no option for .xml in the "New File..." - Dialogue.I tried to copy paste and rename an existing xml File in Xcode´s project navigator (left pane), but then the program gives me an error when I run in the Simulator.

Comment: `File>New>File...` -> `Empty` and then name it `Whatever.xml` before clicking 'Create' or just drag an xml file to the project navigator and make sure 'Copy if needed' is checked.

Answer (score 1):

select the folder and click the right button > add file > select empty file and name it "nameOfTheFile.xml".Now you have it.